# Call built-in PHP class in controller which has namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

How to call a built-in PHP class in a controller which has namespace?

I want to call `DOMDocument` class in my controller:

```
<?php

namespace Vokuro\Controllers;

use Vokuro\Models\Users;
use Vokuro\Models\Games;
use Vokuro\Models\Developers;
use Vokuro\Models\Publishers;
use Vokuro\Models\Terms;
use Vokuro\Models\Taxonomies;

class TestController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($this->get_contents($data->NewsUrl));
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    }
    ....
}
```

but it got error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Vokuro\Controllers\DOMDocument' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vngarena.com\app\controllers\TestController.php on
>   line 78

Comment: Built-in classes are in global namespace: so `$dom = new \DOMDocument();` and `$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);`

Comment: Prefix with a backslash to get the global namespace.

Comment: this should be the correct answer, not just a comment